# Get sprite sheet background position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table where each cell background is populated by sprites from a sprite sheet when the user clicks the cell which applies a class.

```
#design_container td {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url("../img/material_sprite.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.material_58 {
  background-position: -192px -48px;
}
```

Now I am using html5 canvas to make a download image. How can I get the background-position of the cells?
I tried(and failed)

```
let x = document.querySelector('.material_58').style.backgroundPosition;
console.log(x); // returned nothing/blank
```

And also to no avail:

```
let tmp = window.getComputedStyle(x,null).backgroundPosition.trim().split(/\s+/);
```

I assume they may be getting the background position of the actual element, not the position of the sprite sheet.
I'm trying to get

```
background-position: -192px -48px;
```

If something like that doesn't work maybe something like get the actual class description and parse it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that you're referencing a nonexistent `style` attribute on the element. What you want is the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.material_58');
const bgpos = getComputedStyle(element).backgroundPosition;

console.log(bgpos);
```

```css
.material_58 {
  background-position: -192px -48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="material_58"></div>
```

It would work the way you have it if the background position were inline:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('.inline-style')
    .style
    .backgroundPosition
);
```

```html
<div class="inline-style" style="background-position: -192px -48px"></div>
```